# Store data in a variable from a nested foreach loop from eloquent query statement

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

I want to pass data from laravel controller to view. the problem i am having is that the data being passed is coming from a database table and its being stored in a variable using nested foreach loop but the variable is being overritten with each loop. 
Here is the Code.

```
 public function generateContract(Request $request){


    foreach($request->ids as $id){
        $contract = explode(",", $id);
        $this->techId[] = $contract[0];
        $this->meetingId[] = $contract[1];
        $this->contractId[] = $contract[2];
    }


    $names = contract::whereIn('technician_id', $this->techId)->whereIn('meeting_id', $this->meetingId )->get();

    foreach($names as $name){
         $names_arr[] = $name->firstName;

    }

    $unique_names = array_unique($names_arr);

    foreach($unique_names as $unique_name){
        $functions[] = Contract::where('firstName', $unique_name)->whereIn('meeting_id', $this->meetingId)->whereIn('id', $this->contractId)->get();


     }

    return view('contract.generated_contract', compact('unique_names', 'functions'));

}
```

My question is how can i pass the `$functions` variable to view without it being overwritten. I have tried using array but the array is also being overritten with each loop.

Comment: why do you use whereIn in your query? what data do you have in $this->meetingId & $this->contractId? Also, it is a bad practice to executive a query in a loop